# while loop with number of days in a month

Tags: php

I'm trying to get this piece of script to work, but it keeps dying

```
$currentdays = intval(date("t"));

echo $currentdays; //echoes 30 as we're in April
$i = 1;
while ($i <= $currentdays){
    echo $day;
}
```

It keeps dying with no error. I feel like it's timing out, but it's certainly taking its time.

Comment: I always prefer `for` loops because of this :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to increment `$i`. 1 will always be less than 30, creating an infinite loop.

```
$currentdays = intval(date("t"));
$i = 0;

while ($i++ < $currentdays){
    echo $i; // outputs 1, 2, 3.. 30
}
```

Comment: Also - not sure where $day came from, echo $i? - agree with your answer though.

Answer (score 5):

`$i` never changes. Try this:

```
$currentdays = intval(date("t"));

echo $currentdays; //echoes 30 as we're in April
$i = 1;
while ($i++ < $currentdays){
    echo $i;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You never increment $i after echoing $day.  This will go into an infinite loop.